# Как перевести struct tm в time_t с учетом перехода на летнее время?

Tags: c, unix, linux

Столкнулся с задачей: есть какая-то дата, нужно посчитать разницу в секундах между этой датой и текущим временем системы. Т.е мне надо узнать число секунд с начала эпохи до текущего момента, потом до нужной мне даты  и вычесть одно из другого. 
Проблема в том, что нужно еще учитывать переход на зимнее/летнее время.

Пример: На машине `/etc/localtime` ссылается на `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Bucharest`, там у них переход на час вперед в 3:00. 
Допустим, сейчас 27 марта 2011 года, 02:10. Мне нужно установить дату 5:10; если бы это был обычный день, то разница во времени составила бы три часа. Но, в после 2:59:59 наступит сразу 4:00:00, поэтому реально разница между этими датами составляет два часа.

Время я храню в `struct tm`. Там есть поле `tm_isdst` которое вроде как отвечает за то, применяется ли перевод стрелок к заданной дате. Если в моем примере поставить `tm_isdst =1`, то `localtime_r` выдаст правильный результат. Но фокус в том, что для произвольно выбранной даты я не могу сказать, применяется ли к ней перевод стрелок :(

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать вызов mktime(). В передаваемой ему структуре tm переменную tm_isdst установите равной -1. Тогда mktime сам определит - действовало ли для данного времени летнее время или нет.

Comment: спасибо, это оказалось именно то, что нужно было

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. получается, что в день перехода на летнее время у Вас в сутках будет 25 часов?! Это же бред.

Разница во времени в часах не зависит от перехода на летнее и зимнее время. К тому же сейчас уже нет перехода в нашей стране.

Comment: 23 часа. Но в общем верно: если между двумя датами случился переход на зимнее время, надо один час добавить; если на летнее -- отнять. Если оба перехода -- они друг друга компенсируют и результат будет корректным.
В мире еще осталась куча стран, где президенты не думают о своем народе :)

Comment: уважаемый @beardog давайте хоть о политике не будем xD

Answer (score 0):

Если брать время в unix timestamp то вычитывать разницу для перехода на летнее/зимнее время не нужно.